# How to access to site by 2 address

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site now with address `https://example.com/`. How to make possible access to this site also by address `https://example.com.html`? What to write in htaccess?

Comment: You mean you want to be able to use `example.com.html` as the _host name_ to access this site? That can’t be done using .htaccess, that requires modifications at DNS level and in the server configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What to write in htaccess?

Nothing special.

The question is not what to write but what to **not** write in `.htaccess`. And the answer is: do not write anything that links the site to one of its names (`example.com` or `example.com.html`). The same applies to the PHP source or configuration files.

The rest is just proper names registration, nameserver and Apache configuration.

Regarding the configuration of Apache, let's say the IP address of your web server is `1.2.3.4`. The Apache configuration file (`httpd.conf` f.e.) now contains something similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/docs/example.com"
    # Other configuration directives for domain example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In order to let Apache know the domain `example.com.html` is the same as `example.com` you can add a [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) to the [`<VirtualHost>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) block:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com.html
    DocumentRoot "/www/docs/example.com"
    # Other configuration directives for domain example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Assuming you already have the name and the name servers are properly configured to point to your existing server, restart Apache and it should work.

Read more about [`<VirtualHost>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) and [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias)